# can I consume kafka messages based on given list of partition ids and offset#?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

given I have a kafka topic with 4 partitions and each has a few committed messages in it. For some reason I would like to re-play some of the committed messages based on given partition id and offset# , what is the best way to do that with java client lib ?

for example I have

TopicA:

Partition1 : ...offset-1,offset-3,offset-7...

Partition2 : ...offset-2,offset-4,offset-8...

Partition3 : ...offset-5,offset-6,offset-9...

Partition4 : ...offset-10,offset-11,offset-12...

I would like to re-play only

Partition1 : offset-3

Partition2 : offset-8

Partition3 : offset-5

so I have psudo-code like below

```
props.put("max.poll.records", "1"); // to make sure I only get exactly one desired message on that offset 

({(1,3),(2,8),(3,5)}).stream(part_offset-> {
  int i=1; // used as loop count down latch
while(i>=0){
 consumer.assign(get_partition(part_offset.part));
 consumer.seek(new TopicPartition("TopicA", part_offset.part), part_offset.offset);
 records=consumer.pool(Duration.ofSeconds(1)); // I read somewhere kafka is lazy , so should I poll before this ?
 for ( record : records) {
  //do something
  i--;
 }

}

})
```

but code above is not working, it is just hanging there doing nothing.
just wondering what would be the best approach to replay some messages with given partition id and offset information ? or , do I consume in a wrong fashion ? Please advise

Thanks a lot

Comment: Does it hang if you just seek to one partition/offset?

Comment: sorry , my bad , I think the problem is the offset has expired and cannot be retrieved even in loop .

Answer (score 0):

sorry , my bad. I did not put a stopper for none existing offset while polling.  so code below is working fine after I put a cap on retry , feel free to comment .But just wondering if it is the best practice to use an int for stopping retry like that ? thanks

```
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
        props.put("max.poll.records", "1");
        props.put("key.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "appname-message-patching");

        List<Pair<Integer,Integer>> partition_offset= Arrays.asList(Pair.of(0,1),Pair.of(0,21),
                Pair.of(1,31) );

        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);

        partition_offset.forEach(po-> {
            TopicPartition tp=new TopicPartition(topicName, po.getKey());
            consumer.assign(Arrays.asList(tp));
            consumer.seek(tp,po.getValue());
            int counter=1;//only get 1 message , double guards for max.poll.records ?
            int retry=5;//retry 5 times then give up if cannot receive anything
            while (counter>0 ) {
                ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(1));

                if(retry>0 || !records.isEmpty()) {
                    for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                        counter--;
                        System.out.printf("==================thread name = %s , partation = %d , offset = %d , key = %s , value = %s\n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), record.partition(), record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
                    }
                    retry--;
                }
                if (retry==0||counter==0){
                    counter=0;break;
                }
            }
        });
        consumer.close();
```